# Is there a shorthand for making a value negative/postive if variable is true false?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to do this without a if else statement and without code-repetition:

```
const centerY = down ? side*0.866:-side*0.866
```

Comment: At least without repetition `(down ?  -1 : +1) * side * 0.866`. If you use it more than once just extract a `sign` variable

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Best readable + understandable suggestion so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate with the boolean value of `down`

```
const centerY = (2 * down - 1) * side * 0.866
```

or with bitwise NOT

```
const centerY = (~(~1 * down)) * side * 0.866
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a variable.

```
let v = side*0.866;
const centerY = (down && v) || -v;
```

Or without a variable

```
const centerY = (down && 1 || -1) * side * 0.866
```